# Android: JobScheduler sometimes reuses the same job instance?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jobscheduler

I always thought that if you schedule a job it would always create a new JobService instance for that job. After some testing, it looks like it uses the same job instance sometimes? Sometimes it would create a new instance, sometimes not. I would even cancel the prev job before starting a new one and the behavior is still the same. Is this normal?

EDIT:
I am using 3 jobs ids that share the same job class.

```
val jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
jobScheduler.cancel(jobId)

// Set up the JobBuilder
val builder = JobInfo.Builder(jobId, componentName)
     .setRequiredNetworkType(networkType)
     .setPeriodic(uploadFrequency)
     .setPersisted(true)
     .setExtras(bundle)

// Schedule
jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build())
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `JobScheduler` directly (which has known issues on every API level) instead of using [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) (which includes workarounds for all those issues and has a much more consistent API behavior)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake hey, the app I'm working on is for M and up so I thought I could just use JobScheduler directly. Didn't know it was riddled with serious bugs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest workaround for the issue I was facing was to not to share the same job class between job ids.

For example:
JobId 100, 101, and 102 should not be associated w/ the same job class, say `BackgroundJobService`.

Instead they need to be associated w/ diff distinct classes so it should be 3 jobs that extend from `BackgroundJobService`.

```
jobId 100 -> class JobService100: BackgroundJobService(){}
jobId 101 -> class JobService101: BackgroundJobService(){}
jobId 102 -> class JobService102: BackgroundJobService(){}
```

If the job ids share the same class, you run into issues where the JobScheduler would reuse instances created from other job ids.